# How to set first tab as a default tab always with ngSwitch using Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how can i may with [ngSwitch] Tabs first tab should to be default always (without Components).

Hier existing Code, Planker sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TbjRN56oHXCDIzSBQ0vp?p=preview

I tried with ng-content for Multiple structor like this:

```
<ng-content *ngSwitchDefault *ngIf="viewMode !== 'map' || viewMode !== 'list'> Default ! should be TAB 1 </ng-content>
```

But this doesn't work.

PS: Ignore Bootstrap classes in the Code.

Comment: Why don't you wish to set the `viewMode` variable to `map` in your component code?

Comment: Yes, just   viewMode='map' in the class?

Comment: ng switch is the default in your code? maybe you can elaborate your question more

Comment: Oh my mistake, your are right, i should set Default in the class...